# Firestore Snapshot Listeners: Realtime Updates Best Practices and Churn Rate

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

According to Firestore's Best Practices docs (below), one should avoid adding and removing snapshot listeners in quick succession. The docs state, "snapshot listeners should have a lifetime of 30 seconds or longer." However, because a snapshot subscribe and subsequent unsubscribe is controlled by the user's actions (e.g. navigation to and away from a particular page), it may not be possible to always to keep a connection open for more than 30 seconds.

As an example, my app has an Account Details page. The page has one listener the subscribes to the main details (i.e. Account Name, Primary Address, Primary Contact, etc.). The page also has several tables (e.g. Locations, Inventory, Purchase Orders, etc.) each of which has their own listener.

That being said, would it be problematic if my users navigate between several Account Details pages very quickly (since each page will be opening and closing its own set of 3-5 listeners)? If it is problematic, what type of issues will this create for my app? For instance, would Firestore simply slow down temporarily? Or could there be bigger issues with data consistency (i.e. where the snapshot temporarily shows old snapshot data while waiting for the new snapshot to prime)?

Here's what is stated in Firestore's Best Practices documentation:

> Avoid frequently churning listeners, especially when your database is under significant write load.
>
> Ideally, your application should set up all the required snapshot listeners soon after opening a connection to Cloud Firestore. After setting up your initial snapshot listeners, you should avoid quickly adding or removing snapshot listeners in the same connection.
>
> To ensure data consistency, Cloud Firestore needs to prime each new snapshot listener from its source data and then catch up to new changes. Depending on your database's write rate, this can be an expensive operation.
>
> Your snapshot listeners can experience increased latency if you frequently add or remove snapshot listeners to references. In general, a constantly-attached listener performs better than attaching and detaching a listener at that location for the same amount of data. For best performance, snapshot listeners should have a lifetime of 30 seconds or longer. If you encounter listener performance issues in your app, try tracking your app's listens and unlistens to determine if they may be happening too frequently.
>
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#realtime_updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rapidly adding and removing listeners due to such user action won't create technical problems, but it just means you'll be using more resources than you'd ideally like.

If you imagine that many users may follow this same click path that you describe, consider running a single query that gets you the data for all those screens in one go. That might mean you need a different/additional data structure, but on the other hand also means you have less churn in setting up/tearing down listeners.

But again, this is not a technical limit in any way. It is merely an observation of patterns that the writers of that documentation have seen get the best value out of Firestore.